# Remove child list item when checking grandchild list using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

The following code shows how I am assigning data into `IEnumerable<UnCompletedJobDetailsBO>`.

There is a list (`IEnumerable<UnCompletedJobDetailsBO>`) that has another list (`List<JobDetailsBO>`), with that child list (`List<JobDetailsBO>`) having a list on it. But the `AllocationDetailList` only ever has one list item.

```
public IEnumerable<UnCompletedJobDetailsBO> GetControlDetails(DateTime startDate)
{
    var controlDetails =
       (from booking in db.BookingDetail
        where booking.BookingDateTime >= startDate
        orderby booking.DocketNo
        select new UnCompletedJobDetailsBO()
        {
            CustomerName = booking.Customer.Name,
            CompanyName = booking.CompanyDetail.Name,
            JobList =
               (from job in db.BookingJob.Where(x => x.BookingID == booking.BookingID) //get job list
                select new JobDetailsBO()
                {
                    JobID = job.JobID,
                    JobType = job.JobType,
                    ItemName = job.ItemName,
                    AllocationDetailList =
                       (from jobAllocationDetail in db.JobAllocation
                        join returnUnCollected in db.JobReturnUnCollected
                            on jobAllocationDetail.JobAllocationDetailID
                            equals returnUnCollected.JobAllocationDetailID
                            into returnJob

                        from returnUnCollected in returnJob.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where (jobAllocationDetail.Booking.BookingID == booking.BookingID)
                        select new AllocationBO()
                        {
                            JobUnCollectedID = returnJob.JobUnCollectedID,
                            JobType = jobAllocationDetail.JobType,
                            CurrentStatus = jobAllocationDetail.CurrentStatus,
                        }).DefaultIfEmpty().ToList(),
                }).DefaultIfEmpty().ToList(),
        }).ToList();

    return controlDetails;
}
```

I want to remove the `JobList` item if the inner list (`AllocationDetailList`) item satisfies the condition below. Sometimes `AllocationDetailList` may be null, so I check that also. But when I write below query, it does not remove that particular `JobList` item that satisfies the condition. Thanks in advance.

```
public List<UnCompletedJobDetailsBO> RemovePODFromSelectedList(
    List<UnCompletedJobDetailsBO> unCompletedJobDetailsBO)
{
    unCompletedJobDetailsBO
        .SelectMany(y => y.JobList)
        .ToList()
        .RemoveAll(x => ((x.AllocationDetailList[0] != null) ?
            x.AllocationDetailList[0].JobType == "D" &&
                x.AllocationDetailList[0].JobUnCollectedID == null &&
                x.AllocationDetailList[0].CurrentStatus == 5 :
            x.AllocationDetailList.Count > 1));

    return unCompletedJobDetailsBO;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without [a good, *minimal*, *complete* code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), I'm not sure that any performance concern can be addressed. It's hard enough to fully understand the question as it is, but without being able to actually test the code, to reproduce and observe a specific performance concern, it's hard to know for sure where your concern specifically lies, never mind how to fix it.

That said, from the code you posted, it *is* clear why items are not being removed from the list. The basic issue is that while the `SelectMany()` method does have the effect of allowing you to enumerate all of the elements from all of the different `JobList` objects as a single enumeration, the elements are enumerated as a *new* enumeration.

When you call `ToList()`, you are creating a whole new list from that new enumeration, and when you call `RemoveAll()`, you are only removing elements from that new list, not the lists from which they originally came.

You say you can get it to work with a `for` loop. I assume you mean something like this:

```
public List<UnCompletedJobDetailsBO> RemovePODFromSelectedList(
    List<UnCompletedJobDetailsBO> unCompletedJobDetailsBO)
{
    foreach (var item in unCompletedJobDetailsBO)
    {
        item.JobList.RemoveAll(x => ((x.AllocationDetailList[0] != null) ?
            x.AllocationDetailList[0].JobType == "D" &&
                x.AllocationDetailList[0].JobUnCollectedID == null &&
                x.AllocationDetailList[0].CurrentStatus == 5 :
            x.AllocationDetailList.Count > 1));
    }

    return unCompletedJobDetailsBO;
}
```

Note: there is no need to return `unCompletedJobDetailsBO`. That entire object is unchanged, never mind the variable. The only thing the code is modifying is each individual `JobList` object within the passed-in object's members. I.e. the above method could actually have a return type of `void`, and the `return` statement could be removed entirely.

It is *possible* you could speed the code up by removing the elements in a different way. The `List<T>.RemoveAll()` method is in fact reasonably efficient, with O(n) cost. But it still involves copying all of the data in the list after the first element that is removed (so that all the elements are shifted down in the list). If you have to have the list ordered, this may be as good as you can do, but if not, you could process the removal differently, or use a different data structure altogether, something unordered where removal of one or more elements costs less.

But again, without more details and without a good example to work with addressing that particular issue doesn't seem practical here.

Comment: Sorry to didn't provide the complete code. This codes in the same DA file. I want the filtered list in to my controller. I agree with your answer. Without forloop/ foreach I can't do?

Comment: Given the information provided so far, no...I don't see a way to do it without visiting each `UnCompletedJobDetailsBO` object in your main list. Note that even your non-working example actually did that...it just did so in a less obvious way.

Comment: Ya i am using ToList(). It load all the List before filtering. This same as using foreach. It is any possible way to do this in the lazy/deferred level. RemoveAll needs List. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you mean by "lazy/deferred level". But you could make your original query deferred by removing the last `ToList()`, and you could add a `where` to the initialization of the `JobList` property to take into account some filtering you want to do, so that the elements just don't wind up in the list in the first place. It's not clear to me that's what you're asking though.

Comment: My first fault is using ToList() at the query. If I didn't use ToList my output should be IEnumerable<UnCompletedJobDetailsBO>. But unable to Apply RemoveAll() for IEnumerable<T>. Is it any way to remove item from IEnumerable<T> without applying where in the query

Comment: _"Is it any way to remove item from IEnumerable<T> without applying where in the query"_ -- no, there's not. An instance of `IEnumerable<T>` isn't a collection per se. It's simply a sequence of values; the only way to "remove" something from a sequence is to enumerate it and skip the elements you don't want. But note that if you delay evaluation of the outermost enumeration, that delays _all_ evaluation in the query, which means you can include filter criteria on the inner members (like `JobList`), and have it applied when you evaluate the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

The condition

```
x.AllocationDetailList[0] != null
```

will throw exception if there is no item in the AllocationDetailList. Instead you need to check

```
x.AllocationDetailList!=null && x.AllocationDetailList.Count>0.
```

Also .ToList() after SelectMany in your code will create a new list and items will be removed from that new list instead of unCompletedJobDetailsBO. You need to modify the remove function as below

```
   unCompletedJobDetailsBO.ForEach(y => y.JobList.RemoveAll(x => ((x.AllocationDetailList != null && x.AllocationDetailList.Count>0) 
                                                                         ?
                                                                         x.AllocationDetailList[0].JobType == "D"
                                                                           && x.AllocationDetailList[0].JobUnCollectedID == null
                                                                           && x.AllocationDetailList[0].CurrentStatus == "5" 
                                                                         :
                                                                        x.AllocationDetailList.Count > 1
                                                                         )
                                                                   ));
```